# DAX - Work out days in an overlapping period

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am fairly new to DAX and seem to be coping ok so far but I am completely stuck on an issue. I think it relates to 'in progress' events

I have a "Leave" table which shows periods of Annual Leave, Sick, and Public Holidays. I want to calculate how much of each has been taken the previous month. To add to the complication, I only wish to calculate working days of each. I have a related "Calendar" table that has a column called "Working Day" so I've just been using COUNTROWS and filtering to Yes to only show these rows. The part I'm struggling with is sometimes the period on a row will run over more than one month as you can see with the "SICK" row. For example I'd expect the values for Sick to show -

June - 6
July - 22
August - 1

Can this be done with a measure?

[image]

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Add source table and your desired output

Comment: The attached photo on the original question is the source table, it’s from an excel file. My desired output for SICK for example would be -

Month Working Days
June 6
July 22
August 1

Does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this solution:

```
LeaveWorkDay = 
var __date = GENERATE(Leave, FILTER('Calendar', 'Calendar'[Date] >= [Start] && 'Calendar'[Date] <= [End] && 'Calendar'[workingdays] = 1))
return
countrows(__date)
```

where my test model looks like:

[image]

Used field:
[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, does exactly what I need!